# Split really large file into smaller files in Python - Too many open files

Tags: python, bigdata

I have a really large csv file (close to a Terabyte) that I want to split into smaller csv files, based on info in each row.

Since there is no way to do that in memory, my intended approach was to read each line, decide which file it should go into, and append it there. This however takes ages, since opening and closing takes too long.

My second approach was to keep all files (about 3000) open - this however does not work since I can't have so many files open in parallel.

Additional details as requested: The .csv file contains map data I need to access region-wise. Therefore, I plan on clustering it into files covering different bounding boxes. Since it is unsorted data, I have to process the lat/lon of each row, assign the correct file to it, and append the row to the file.

What would be a working (fast, ideally) approach for that?

Comment: How is the data structured? Can the data be seperated by `split` (the unix command line utility) or is it variable in size?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the file?

Comment: are you on a *nix system? the OS can do it for you using `split`

Comment: @aws_apprentice: No, unfortunately, I have to use Windows.

Comment: @ThatBird: I edited my question with additional details

Comment: Do it in memory.  Don't write each line to a file; write it to some kind of data structure (a list, etc).  When the data structure gets "too big", append it to a corresponding file and "reset" the data structure.  That way you have many fewer open/closes.

Comment: don't use `pandas`, use the `csv` library which opens the file using a lazy iterator, write out `n` lines and rinse and repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be somewhat of a hacky method but it would require `pandas` and doing some batched appends. This will solve the issue with having to open and close files during every row processing. I'm going to assume that the way you triage the rows to your CSV's is based on some value from a column in your large CSV.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df_chunked = pd.read_csv("myLarge.csv", chunksize=30000)  # you can alter the chunksize

for chunk in df_chunked:
    uniques = chunk['col'].unique().tolist()
    for val in uniques:
        df_to_write = chunk[chunk['col'] == val]
        if os.path.isfile('small_{}.csv'.format(val)):  # check if file already exists
            df_to_write.to_csv('small_{}.csv'.format(val), mode='a', index=False, header=False)
        else:
            df_to_write.to_csv('small_{}.csv'.format(val), index=False)
```

Comment: I'll have to do a little post-processing, but this might indeed be a way to do it. Thanks! I'll leave the question open for now to see whether any other suggestions arrive.

Comment: I love Python! I was basically able to copy & paste your solution, fit it to my problem, and it has been running for 10 minutes now with constant memory consumption. This will take all weekend to finish, but so far, your solution seems to work flawlessly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although i agree with the comments that knowing the details of the file would be essential to providing an actual working answer, i had a similar issue and resolved it using pandas.

The .read_csv method of pandas will use the csv reader to only partially read the csv files without loading the whole file into memory. Best is to do some trial and error and see how many rows at a time is your system able to support

```
import pandas as pd
num_rows = 6000 # or some value which depends on system memory 
NewDf1 =pd.DataFrame()
NewDf2 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(start,stop,num_rows):
    rawdata_df = pd.read_csv(filename,skiprows=range(1,i),nrows=num_rows) 
    NewDf1.append(rawdata_df[rawdata_df.iloc[1]>0],ignore_index=True)
    NewDf2.append(rawdata_df[rawdata_df.iloc[2]>0],ignore_index=True)
```

At the end depending on your actual system memory and structure of files (because the size of dataframe depends also on number of columns and structure of data) you can save the separate dataframes in separate csvs

```
 if len(NewDf1) > toolarge:
      NewDf1.to_csv('newdf1Filename.csv')
```

Comment: Would "skiprows" not necessitate reading the file from the beginning to count the newlines? This would probably take a long time when I get to the end of my huge file...

Comment: unfortunately i dont have a nice benchmark. With skiprows for me for multi-GB files it was ok (wouldnt call it blitzing fast) since it doesnt read line by line. The other answer on 'chunksize' also seems interesting - but i couldnt make out if performance wise it is similar [http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking]. If you would be kind enough to test and report would be super helpful